# In rails how to detect sub pages with if current_page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use `current_page?` to detect the current page and style that link differently like this :

```
<li class="snavitem <%= ' active' if current_page? countries_path %>">
```

Now if we are at `/countries` then this will add the active class to the link which will make it different. But how to style the link like this when we are in sub pages like `countries/new`, `countries/edit` ?

Comment: Try my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Define a method `check_action` in application helper

```
def check_action controller, action
  return true if controller.eql?("countries") and (action.includes?("index") or action.includes?("edit") or action.includes?("new"))
end
```

In view

```
<li class="snavitem <%= ' active' if check_action(controller, controller.action_name) %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is smth like this:

```
current_page?(controller: 'countries')

countries/ #=> true
countries/anything-here #=> true
```

Comment: Try to look here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.fullpath` to get current full path

example

```
<ul>
 <% Contry.all.each do |c| %>
  <li class="snavitem <%= is_active?(edit_contry_path(c)) %>">
    <%= link_to "edit " + c.name, edit_contry_path(c) %>
  </li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

and on your `application_helper.rb`

```
def is_active?(link_path)
  "active" if request.fullpath == link_path
end
```

read about request.fullpath [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-fullpath)